# NetBeans 12.0, Java 8, autocomplete/code assistance completely stopped working

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete, ide

Autocomplete isn't working in my NetBeans IDE. It's a fresh installation, didn't change any settings. Reinstalled a couple of times. Not sure what I did to break it.

Java version is assigned in the settings and it does compile and run Java programs.

I have the following installed:

- NetBeans IDE 12.0
- Java 8 Update 271
- Java 8 Update 271 (64-bit) Java
- SE Development Kit 8 Update 191 (64-bit)

Does anyone have an idea what it could be?

[image]

Comment: Go to `Tools > Options > Code Completion`. Is `Auto Popup Completion Window` selected for all languages? Can you share a screen shot of that window if it doesn't fix it?

Comment: @acm Added a screenshot

Comment: Is the `Ctrl + Space` showing the completion popup or that is also failing?

Comment: @acm Also failing. It shows no options.

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce your issue. What I would do if I was you would be to uninstall Netbeans. Right after that, delete both config and cache. In linux that would be `rm -rf ~/.netbeans ~/.cache/netbeans`. Then reinstall, that way you really start fresh.

Comment: OK, I would like to rant about why this question got closed. It is perfectly reasonable, and it chances that I have the same issue. But OK. Rant stopped. In my case Netbeans profile directory apparently got somehow corrupted. I suspect that this happened because of my inattentive handling og jVi plugin that I think needs to be careful with.

TL;DR it is more sensible to remove the profile folder, which e.g. could be like: C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.0     - next time Netbeans starts, it will create it anew. But you lose all Plugins, Options and what not.

Comment: @hello_earth Thanks for your input. I notice that a lot of times useful posts get closed rather than answered here.. I also removed the profile folder and the cache and that fixed it.

Comment: Dear bro, I have this problem too, I use older version, the NetBeans IDE 8.0.2, it working too fast and too better than newest version.

Comment: I had this problem after installing the spring plugin for netbeans, looking into @hello_earth comment i tried deleting the "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Cache\NetBeans\12.0" folder instead of the one he indicates. After a netbeans reboot everything works fine now, and my plugins weren't remove.